# Question about subscriptions in In-App purchase

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, subscriptions

After attending an iPhone dev conf in San Jose - I left with more questions about In-App purchasing than when I started.  Here's what I was wondering:

You can set a purchase as a type "subscription".  cool.  But, it doesn't say anywhere about how the subscription is serviced - how does apple know to charge once a month?  once a week? one every six months? etc.  I was told that apple doesn't really do that - only that it calls it a type of subscription.  That the developer must be the one to monitor the subscriptions and then submit them to apple when they are due up - but this leads to another question - then why have the subscription type?  If I monitor the days until it's due, then submit it to apple as an application charge - what's the difference in merely making separate charges on a regular basis?

it seems to me, apple is doing nothing on the subscriptions - only declaring the type - all the work is done by the developer - in which case, why call it a subscription?

Can someone point me to some code that handles a subscription for an app - and what they had to do to set this up for recurring payments?  Would greatly appreciate it....

many thanx.

peace.  JOe...

Comment: Look at it from the user's perspective: A subscription will be periodically billed where a simple purchase will be one time.  Further from Apple's perspective they will expect periodic charges from the developer for a subscription without the user's explicit permission each time.

Comment: I'm not sure about this.  The example I saw showed the subscription being charged - but the user had to okay it first on his phone before it went through.  So, you need the user's explicit permission each time the charge is attempted.  Like I said in my post, this kinda makes subscriptions pointless - it's the same as having a single charge that just gets sent each time.  Maybe I'm missing something in the dox or whatever - but nothing sticks out as negating what I've seen/understood so far...

Answer (score 3):

Subscriptions in the iPhone SDK really are to get around the fact that you cannot sell virtual credits, therefore what you can do is sell a subscription and make the digital content free from within your application assuming the user has a subscription to your service, you are correct in that you have to handle the majority of the logic yourself